# cant send data to another activity because of number format exception

Tags: android, kotlin, exception

from here im sending data

```
                val intent = Intent(this@Level1,ScoringActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("Scoring", mCurrentPosition.toString())

                intent.putExtra("categoryType",categoryType)
                startActivity(intent)
```

from here im receiving data

```
     if (intent.getStringExtra("Scoring")?.toInt()?: 0 >= displayBest().toInt()) {

        val preferences: SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Scoring", MODE_PRIVATE)

        val editor: SharedPreferences.Editor = preferences.edit()
        editor.putString("best", intent.getStringExtra("Scoring")).toString()
        editor.commit()
        }

    }
```

in if statement im getting Number Format Exception

Answer (score 0):

You can use `putInt` and `getIntExtra` methods for it. So you don't need to convert numbers to string.

```
  intent.putInt("Scoring", mCurrentPosition)

   intent.getIntExtra("Scoring",0)
```